# Multiple Http calls in one array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am wondering what should be the 'best case' approach for this situation.

I have to display posts, user name(s) and related comments to posts.
Posts http call has userId property and comments http call has 'postId'. So, in that case I would need to call 3 http calls to fetch all that I need (posts, user information and comments).

What should be a best approach? Should I use map, so in a moment when I gain all posts, I should map user name from userId and after that map comments?

EDIT: I have no backend, I am using https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ for getting data.

Comment: Please be more precise what you are currently trying to do. Are you doing 3 seperate calls for "somePost" "someUser" and "someRelatedComments" all by themselfes without any relation here?
Or is there a relation you need to resolve based on data you get (e.g. the userIds are contained within the comments, which themselves can be found by the commentIds within the posts)?

Comment: I would typically expect a backend and a database to have these relations figured out for you so the amount of latency by communication between BE and FE is minimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would be to call one endpoint with necessary data but this requires change on backend.

If change on backend is not an option and You have no middleware to support UI it depends on what You need in this case but from what you've described it seems that [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin), [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) or [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) is what You should use if calls are independent, if You need to have output of previous calls to call next ones You can use [flatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) or [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap). It's hard to say without looking at code but I think that some of mentioned operators should do the trick.

Comment: This is what I wanted!!! Thanks :)
p.s. I edited my first post, I don't have backend since I am using jsonplaceholder.typicode and this app is just for training. 
Thank you once again

Comment: Glad to help bro :)